# $u_t + uu_x=2$ where $u(x,0)=x$. Are there any shock forming with this initial condition?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

Consider the initial value problem for $x \in \mathbb R~\text{and}~t>0$: $$u_t + uu_x=2$$ where $u(x,0)=x$.

Are there any shock forming with this initial condition? I'm not quite sure how to show this, though I can definitely solve the equation by method of characteristics. Thanks.

Comment: So what solution did you find? Do the characteristics collide or not?

Comment: @HansLundmark Sorry, what do you mean by what solution did I find? I just solved it by method of characteristics. I don't quite understand you second question. Could you be more specific since I'm quite new to the shocks part.

Comment: Well, I just mean that if you know the solution already, it should be completely obvious (just by looking at the solution) whether there is any shock formation or not.

Comment: (And shock formation happens when characteristics collide, so that the function $u(x,t)$ is “trying to have two different values at once”.)

Comment: @HansLundmark When the Jacobian is zero?

Comment: Perhaps if you edit the question to include how far you have actually come, it would be easier to help you. In this case, what I mean by “solving the equation” is that for this you can find a completely explicit expression for the solution $u(x,t)=\ldots$, and once you have that, the answer to your question should be immediately obvious.

Comment: @HansLundmark Just added an answer. Feel free to correct me or edit my answer if you think it's wrong.

Comment: @HansLundmark Just did it. Not sure whether it's correct though.

Comment: @HansLundmark This link seems helpful (https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-303-linear-partial-differential-equations-fall-2006/lecture-notes/quasi.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is $u(x,t)= \frac{x+t^2 + 2t}{t+1}$

$\frac{dx}{dr}=u$,$\frac{dt}{dr}=1$ and $\frac{du}{dr}=2$ with $\Gamma: (s,0,s)$. So $\frac{dx}{ds}=r+1$, $\frac{dt}{ds}=0$ and we can calculate the Jacobian of $x(r,s)$ and $t(r,s)$: -r-1=0, which means $t$ needs to be -1, so, it's impossible to have a shock, right?

Comment: Almost, but not quite. If you plug your formula into the PDE, you'll see that it's not satisfied. If you think of the geometric interpretation (points at height $u$ travel with velocity $u$), then it should be clear that $u(0,t)=0$ must hold for all $t$, and in fact one can even see that the solution should be $u(x,t)=x/(t+1)$ (the initial straight line $u(x,0)=x$ gets less and less steep). But yes, your conclusion is correct: there's no shock for $t>0$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you so much. My bad, the RHS of the equation is $2$. I just edited.

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense!